# PORQUE AL GRABAR EN UN ARCHIVO.TXT EN PYTHON ME LO GRABA ALTERNANDO SALTOS DE LINEA

Tags: python

Cuando grabo información en un archivo txt pasa que se graba alternando saltos de linea, no se porque se produce eso.

```
def grabar(self):
        archivo=open("alumnos.txt","w",encoding="utf-8")
        for i in range(len(self.__listaAlumnos)):
            obj=self.__listaAlumnos[i]
            cadena=obj.dni+","
            cadena+=obj.nombre+","
            cadena+=obj.fecha+"\n"
            archivo.write(cadena)
        archivo.close()
```

con este codigo efectuo la grabacion de datos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi se graba en el txt.

Comment: Porque es lo que tú has programado: `cadena+=obj.fecha+"\n"` `\n` es un salto de línea...

Comment: Lo que quiero es que el archivo quede de la siguiente manera:
1478965,ghgfhgfhfh,01/01/2000
1254,ñññññññ,01/01/2022
18444,ffff,01/01/2000
77,7777,01/01/2000
4455,gdfvgfdgdfg,01/01/2000
sin esos saltos de linea alternados porque si le quito ese "\n" todo saldria junto.

Comment: Lo más probable es que el campo fecha (que no vemos cómo se asigna) ya contenga un `\n`, por lo que el `\n` adicional que le sumas causa una línea en blanco.